# Saving UIImage to PhotoLibrary Swift 4.2 iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift

I am applying some filters to the UIImage and then assigning it to the PhotoImageView. When the user presses the done button I want to save the image to the Photo Library. The below code does not save anything and also does not throw any error. The "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" key has already been added to the info.plist file.

```
 @IBAction func doneButtonPressed() {

        // save the picture in the photo library
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.photoImageView.image!, nil, nil, nil);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a selector to get your callback.

```
//MARK: - Save image

func saveImage() {

    guard let selectedImage = imageTake.image else {
        return
    }

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

//MARK: - Save Image callback

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {

    if let error = error {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    } else {

        print("Success")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added your code and the success is getting fired but I never see the edited image in the photo library. It is not saving to the photos album.

Comment: Well when you get the callback it is saving :) Maybe you're not looking at the right destination in your photo album?

Comment: Or is this maybe related to your issue? https://www.reddit.com/r/hackingwithswift/comments/7pa9bx/project_13_not_saving_the_edited_images/

Comment: Thanks! Although I am not sure what context they are talking about. My filters are applied correctly.

Comment: Well have you been able to figure it out?

Comment: Yes David! Thanks a lot I was able to solve the problem.