# How would you write an image (e.g. PNG) and save it to your local desktop in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm generating a `UIImage` from a `View` and I'd like to save it to my desktop so I can view the output and see if I'm saving the correct view. What's the process to save an image to my local machine?

I'm not able to find the documentation on how to save it to my desktop.

Comment: What business does your iOS app have with the destop of the computer you are using?  So far, what you are saying doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading your question it looks like you want to save an image made in iOS app to your Mac desktop.

Here is no easy way to achieve it.

If you running app in simulator you can save image in app sandbox container.
You can see content of all containers in

```
/Users/{USERNAME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{long uuid of simulator}/data/Containers
```

If you running the app on device, easiest way is to save an image in photo library
[Saving UIImage to PhotoLibrary Swift 4.2 iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095345/saving-uiimage-to-photolibrary-swift-4-2-ios-12)

---

Assuming that you running MacOS app.

If you talking about Catalyst and `UIImage` than getting `Data` from image is as easy as:

```
image.pngData()
```

If you meant `NSImage`, than process is more complex:

```
let tiffData = image.tiffRepresentation! // don't forget to check for nil
let pngData = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffData)?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
```

Then just write data via

```
data.write(to: url)
```

Comment: Thank you! In terms of generating the URL, I'm trying `let path =  FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.desktopDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask)` but I'm getting an error, I think I'm not understanding how to generate those URLs

Comment: Seems related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120801

Comment: Wrong domain mask: `FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`

Comment: awesome, thank you!

Comment: @elyakshaver I update answer with approach for iOS apps

Comment: thank you :]. Highly appreciated

Comment: @ManWithBear: I am wondering how could macOS app Swift/SwiftUI have `.pngData()` function because it  belongs UIKit! also wondering how could be your answer be useful! but it seems The OP is ok.

Comment: @swiftPunk in age of Catalyst you can expect everything :D But you are right, `NSImage` doesn't have `.pngData()`. My bad

Comment: @swiftPunk should be fixed. Feel free to edit answer if you think I missed something. Thanks